# Case insensitive but case preserving substitute function, excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a way to do this, i.e.  `Foo`, `FOO`, and `fOO` would come out as `Bar`, `BAR`, and and `bAR`, without having to individually type all possible permutations into the function.

=`SUBSTITUTE(A1,"foo","bar")` is case sensitive, `SUBSTITUTE(lower(A1),"foo", "bar")` is good for some applications, but removes any existing case distinctions from A1; so `FoofooFOO` would go to `barbarbar`. Obviously you can use multiple substitutions to catch all occurences, but when sometimes this is a real pain.

Many thanks.

Comment: No, there is no easy solution for that. the quickest is probably to write a search term for each variant.

Comment: @MátéJuhász There must be a way though. I mean even outside of a UDF couldn't you do one function that returns an array of the cases of the letters and another than then reimposes that case on the end result.  Ugly, but a solution...

Comment: Yes, of course there are many possibilities with vba, but your question is tagged as [worksheet-function]. Also asking for a UDF would be too broad here as you probably know...

Comment: @MátéJuhász outside of a UDF I said

Comment: Never assume you know who downvoted. It's usually not the people commenting. That said, do you have to have matching case on output, or are you just trying to figure out how to handle any possible input case consistently?

Comment: @music2myear unless I'm misunderstanding you, I already addressed that in the question.

Comment: If you must avoid VBA, you can set up an array of case in a bunch of helper columns; use that to adjust the case of your original result, and then concatenate the final result.  If you have the latest version of Excel 2016, you may be able to use the `CONCAT` function to concatenate a range.  You also need to determine how to handle the instances where the replacement string is longer than the original string.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld see below for my solution where I did exactly this

Answer (score 0):

An ugly, but functional answer.

Works for any 2 strings of the same length.

Just putting my hat in the ring, hoping someone can come up with a better solution (array formula perhaps?)

Requires helper columns.  The top row of the helper columns was used used for an Index.

[image]

Formulae:

```
 A2      : (original string)
 C1      : blank, or 0 (needed for next column)
 C2:C... : =SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A2),"FOO","BAR")
 D1      : =B1+1
 D2:D... : =IF(EXACT(MID($A2,C$1,1),UPPER(MID($A2,C$1,1))),MID($B2,C$1,1),LOWER(MID($B2,C$1,1)))
 B2      : concatenate (or textjoin if you're using new excel)
```

Drag Column D until you have enough columns.  Eyeball it, or use `=max(len(A:A))` to find the maximum length.

Comment: Your solution is good for 3 character long strings, but what about longer ones? Do you have a more realistic use case?

Comment: My case is good for any 2 strings of the same length.  , Admittedly a more general solution might want to deal with strings of different lengths.  However; it's unclear exactly how these cases really *should* be handled, it would depend on the user's specific needs.  I'll have a think about it, but in the meantime this is a the solution for the case I needed.

Comment: @MátéJuhász what I mean by that is that If I had "GOODBYE" and "HELLO".  How *should* "GoodBye" be handled?  "hello"? "Hello"?  "HellO"? "HELLO"?  It's not necessarily clear, and it's not the case for which I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Excel supports Lambda functions, a non-VBA answer:

```
SUBSTITUTE_I = LAMBDA(Text, OldText, NewText, [InstanceNum],
    IFS(
        Text = "", "",
        OldText = "", Text,
        TRUE, LET(
            _oldLen, LEN(OldText),
            _maxInstance, INT(LEN(Text) / _oldLen),
            _pos, SCAN(0, SEQUENCE(1, _maxInstance),
                LAMBDA(_acc, _curr,
                    IF(_acc = "", "", IFERROR(SEARCH(OldText, Text, _acc + 1), ""))
                )
            ),
            _count, COUNT(_pos),
            _instance, N(InstanceNum),
            IFS(
                _count = 0, Text,
                ABS(_instance) > _count, Text,
                _instance > 0, REPLACE(Text, INDEX(_pos, 1, _instance), _oldLen, NewText),
                _instance < 0, REPLACE(Text, INDEX(_pos, 1, _count + _instance + 1), _oldLen, NewText),
                TRUE, LET(
                    _lenDiff, LEN(NewText) - _oldLen,
                    _nPos, TAKE(_pos, 1, _count) + SEQUENCE(1, _count, 0, _lenDiff),
                    REDUCE(Text, _nPos,
                        LAMBDA(_acc, _curr,
                            REPLACE(_acc, _curr, _oldLen, NewText)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?